# How to convert OffsetTime to local OffsetTime?

Tags: java, datetime, time, java-8, datetimeoffset

In order to process an `OffsetTime`, I would like to convert it to an local `OffsetTime`. For example convert `14:03:04.708-01:00` to `16:03:04.708+01:00`, if the systems default offset is `+1:00`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`OffsetTime.withOffsetSameInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-):

```
OffsetTime input = OffsetTime.of(14, 3, 4, 708000000, ZoneOffset.ofHours(-1));
System.out.println(input);

OffsetTime output = input.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: This hard codes it, instead of taking the system default.

Comment: thanks, this brings me one step ahead. Yet, it still uses a ZoneOffset constant instead of the systems default.

Comment: Is `OffsetTime.now().getOffset()` the only way to get the systems default offset?

Comment: The problem is that Zones using DST have different offsets during winter and summer

Answer (score 3):

As @Jesper's answer correctly states the way to change the offset on an `OffsetTime` instance, without changing the `Instant` it points to is by invoking `withOffsetSameInstant`.

The hard part is determining the system's default offset. A system does not have a default offset, it has a default `ZoneId`. A `ZoneId` has an offset, but that may change throughout the year, if DST is applied.

It's unclear from your question whether we can determine which time of the year is relevant for your use case. It may be that now is valid for your use case. It may be that you have a `LocalDate` on which the `OffsetTime` is to be evaluated against. If that is the case you can get the system default like this :

```
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, offsetTime.toLocalTime());
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(localDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.
2. The timezone offset of place observing [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) changes as per the summer/winter time. Therefore, if your place observes DST, you should not use a fixed timezone offset e.g. `+01:00` hours; rather, you should get it from the API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strTime = "14:03:04.708-01:00";

        OffsetTime parsedOffsetTime = OffsetTime.parse(strTime);
        System.out.println(parsedOffsetTime);

        OffsetTime offsetTimeAtOffset0100 = parsedOffsetTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+01:00"));
        System.out.println(offsetTimeAtOffset0100);

        // Time at JVM's default timezone offset
        ZoneOffset jvmTzOffset = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getOffset();
        OffsetTime offsetTimeAtJvmTzOffset = parsedOffsetTime.withOffsetSameInstant(jvmTzOffset);
        System.out.println(offsetTimeAtJvmTzOffset);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
14:03:04.708-01:00
16:03:04.708+01:00
16:03:04.708+01:00
```

**Note:** My timezone is `Europe/London` which has an offset of `01:00` hours currently.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>